# Electron OpenGL for MacOs Catalina

Tags: javascript, opengl, electron

I am building an electron application, however i have an error which makes rendering painfully slow and causing high cpu usage

```
[1] Unable to create basic Accelerated OpenGL renderer.
[1] Unable to create basic Accelerated OpenGL renderer.
[1] Core Image is now using the software OpenGL renderer. This will be slow.
```

i try to find out however i couldn't find a answer about the problem. Anyone have any idea about this problem ?

Comment: Also getting this now on Mac Catalina.

Comment: Not sure if related... But i just removed some window event bindings (`beforeunload`, `quit`), and I'm now no longer seeing this issue. (For now at least). Not sure how the two could be linked, but just in case it helps!

Answer (score 4):

Apple deprecated OpenGL in favor of Metal.
https://www.macrumors.com/2018/06/05/apple-deprecates-opengl-opencl-gaming/

There is an open bug in Electron
https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/20944

Comment: So, now that this bug is closed and tossed over the fence to the chromium team, is there are new info/work arounds?