# Can Tkinter Use Metal on macOS Catalina?

Tags: python, macos, opengl, tkinter, metal

I'm trying to run my python tkinter application in a macOS Catalina 10.15.5 VM. When I run, I get:

```sh
Unable to create basic Accelerated OpenGL renderer.
Unable to create basic Accelerated OpenGL renderer.
Core image is now using the software OpenGL renderer. This will be slow.
```

I know from [this github thread](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/20944) and [this stack thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58703593/electron-opengl-for-macos-catalina) that OpenGL has been depreciated in favor of Metal but I'm not sure what that has to do with tkinter since 8.6.10 comes pre-bundled with new python.org installations. Nor am I sure what part of tkinter relies on OpenGL since the most graphics intensive thing in it is matplotlib.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Given the history of bugs on mac run Tk Aqua Coco should I give up using tkinter for macOS at this point?